# HAproxy retries are not working as expected

Tags: haproxy, varnish, http-status-code-503

My http backend (Varnish) sometimes responds with 503 errors for about 2-3 seconds. During that, HAproxy responds with 503 for all requests to that frontend/backend by that client. I want HAproxy to retry the request for a few times, including a pause or timeout between the requests, so that a valid response is given to the client after ~4 seconds.
This is my current backend config

```
backend b_example.com
  retries 10
  retry-on all-retryable-errors
  http-request disable-l7-retry if METH_POST
  server backend_example example.local:80 check inter 1s fall 3 rise 1
```

In the logs, i can see the 10 retries applying. Yet, a 503 is the response to the client and the 10 retries seem instant to me.

Can i somehow put in a delay between the retries?

HAproxy Version: 2.6.12

Answer (score 0):

1. What about increasing the TTL on the varnish side ?
2. in your case, i presume that as soon as your HAproxy is getting a 503, it considers that the whole website is down, which is not what you want.. you probably should have a look on how to implement health-check https://www.haproxy.com/blog/how-to-enable-health-checks-in-haproxy/

if you don't have something like that on your application side, you may implement something quick and dirty on the varnish side to tell haproxy that your varnish is up

```
vcl_recv {
   ...
   if (req.url == "/health") {
      return(synth(200, "OK");
   }
}
```